# Cual es el uso que se le da a las ENI en AWS?

Tags: aws

Esta pregunta es mas teórica. Estoy estudiando para certificar en AWS, estoy leyendo por segunda vez el certified solutions architect study guide de aws y no me queda claro cual es el uso que se le puede dar a una ENI, entiendo que sirven para conectar una VPC con otros servicios. Podria alguien darme una explicacion "for dummies" y algunos ejemplos de uso? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, imagino es la certificación Associate, ¿Conoces el concepto de elasticidad , red elástica?

Comment: Si Jorge, es para asociado. Conozco esos conceptos. No puedo pensar de ejemplos de porque y para que usaría una ENI

Comment: crear subredes con diferentes grupos de seguridad, para simplificar y segmentar. hay un ejemplo en el manual https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#creating-a-management-network

Comment: Recomiendo crear una cuenta de AWS y jugar con las características de EC2 (incluido ENI) para familiarizarse con ellas. Leer un libro solo te llevará hasta cierto punto.

Comment: ok Agrego respuesta @Juan saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ENI es una interfaz de red, que incorpora cierta configuración, que puede incluir direcciones IP, una IP elástica (EIP), varios grupos de seguridad (reglas de firewall), una dirección MAC, un indicador de verificación de origen/destino y una descripción. Se puede conectar un EIN a una instancia EC2 (un servidor virtual); el servidor al que está conectado puede cambiar con el tiempo.

Esto le permite tener un ENI de larga duración que durante su vida útil se puede conectar a muchos servidores de corta duración. Tenemos ENI que no han cambiado durante años que están conectados a instancias EC2 que se reemplazan cada dos semanas.

Comment: Hola Sebastián, podrías añadir a tu respuesta un enlace a la fuente. No veo nada malo en hacer la misma pregunta en inglés para situar la respuesta aquí en español, pero sí me parece correcto aclararlo en el cuerpo de la respuesta: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/401085